# Error with Mysql Syntax in Python Script when Inserting into Database

Tags: mysql, xml, syntax-error

I'm very new to python and mysql also and am currently trying to "INSERT data into a table, events for which I have set up on a WAMP server on my machine. The data I need to store into the database are stored within various arrays within my python program and these have all been stored correctly. I am able to successfully connect to the localhost database via my python program however I am having issues with my mysql syntax when writing to the database.

I hope someone is able to help me - I've basically set up a for loop to write elements stored in an array to the database that I have set up locally on my machine (localhost).

```
length = range(len(event_ids))
imageid = 0 

for z in length:
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO events (event_id, event_title, start_time, stop_time, venue_id, image_id, all_day, venue_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s""" %(event_ids[z], event_names1[z], start_times1[z], stop_times1[z], venue_ids1[z], imageid, all_day_list1[z], venue_names1[z]))
    db.commit()

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

The errors that I receive includes the below information. The elements that are displayed here are reading from the arrays that I have specified successfully "@2013042020, Prodijig Dublin, 2013-04-20 20:00:00, 2013-04-20 23:59:00, V0-001-0:". I just do not know why I receive SQL syntax errors. I'd really appreciate it if anyone can shed any information on where I may be going wrong.

ERRORS:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO events (event_id, event_title, start_time, stop_time, venue_id, image_id, all_day, venue_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s""" %(event_ids[z], event_names1[z], start_times1[z], stop_times1[z], venue_ids1[z], imageid, all_day_list1[z], venue_names1[z]))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in  defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@2013042020, Prodijig Dublin, 2013-04-20 20:00:00, 2013-04-20 23:59:00, V0-001-0' at line 1")
```

EDIT: I have a fix for this code after below discussions however I am now receiving an "IndexError: list index out of range" error for some reason I cannot explain at present and my python program terminates after 35 iterations (when it should iterate and insert elements to database 50 times). If anyone could help me with this too I'd be very appreciative. It might not have to do with this statement however - I am unsure just now.

My fixed mysql insert into code anyway is:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO events (event_id, event_title, start_time, stop_time, venue_id, image_id, all_day, venue_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' , (event_ids[z], event_names1[z], start_times1[z], stop_times1[z], venue_ids1[z], imageid, all_day_list1[z], venue_names1[z]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around all the string values being inserted:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO events (event_id, event_title, start_time, stop_time, venue_id, image_id, all_day, venue_name) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'""" %(event_ids[z], event_names1[z], start_times1[z], stop_times1[z], venue_ids1[z], imageid, all_day_list1[z], venue_names1[z]))
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar I have tried this line of code and receive this following error: 
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")

Comment: could it be anything to do with a " ' " in the strings that I am writing to the database? I can't think of anything else! Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: Single quotes are allowed in mysql queries. Can you print out the query string?

Comment: Well the strings stored within the array in which I am inserting into the database. One such element in the array reads: "South William Space'". This is just a guess though as I feel I have tried so many tutorials and looked through so many answers on stackoverflow that I can't find any other solution.

Comment: I've figured it out that if I remove the '%' before (event_ids[z],...) then I receive a different error highlighting that - "MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'E0-001-052230607-0@2013042020'', ''Prodijig Dublin'', ''2013-04-20 20:00:00'', '' at line 1". This makes me think that the '@' symbol in the string is creating the errors. Is this possible? - Just another guess

Comment: My quoting is unnecessary. Python does the substitution as a MySQL prepared query, not string substitution. I think just removing that `%` may be the only fix you need.

Comment: I have now removed both the quoting and the % and this seems to run and insert 35 of the array elements to my database before terminating. I have however 50 elements stored within my array. I do not know why it terminates, I even checked for funny characters but no such luck -  perhaps it has nothing to do with the mysql query at all. I get the error: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: That sounds like some of the arrays have fewer elements than `event_ids` does.

Comment: You're correct @Barmar. I have found my "stop_time" array contains 15 less than my counter however I wish to print all elements regardless into the database. I am trying to find a solution to this which will check if the "stop_time" contains a value, and if not assigns 'null' and this is passed to the database but I can't find a solution which will check and replace such elements (yet). Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The query you are running is this:

```
INSERT INTO events (
    event_id, 
    event_title, 
    start_time, 
    stop_time, 
    venue_id, 
    image_id, 
    all_day, 
    venue_name) 
VALUES (
    @2013042020, 
    Prodijig Dublin, 
    2013-04-20 20:00:00, 
    2013-04-20 23:59:00, 
    V0-001-0  (rest of query is missing)
```

MySQL is complaining that `@2013042020` is not a valid value. I assume `event_id` is an integer column, so the value should not contain an `@` symbol. Once you fix that you will notice that MySQL has more to complain about your query:

```
Prodijig Dublin     should be a string: 'Prodijig Dublin'
2013-04-20 20:00:00 should be a date  : #2013-04-20 20:00:00# (quotes also work)
2013-04-20 23:59:00 should be a date  : #2013-04-20 23:59:00#
V0-001-0            should be as tring: 'V-0-001-0'
```